# Is the CSS3 best practice of link pseudo classes order different to the CSS2?

Tags: css, hyperlink, pseudo-class

We are used to annotate link pseudo classes linke this:

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

**I assume this order is still correct for CSS3?**

Note: Some propose more precise selectors but that is a different topic:

```
:link:focus, :visited:focus { ... }
:link { ... }
:visited { ... }
:link:hover, :visited:hover { ... }
:link:active, :visited:active { ... }
```

Source: http://www.thestyleworks.de/tut-art/pc_dynamic_a_name.shtml

Comment: The order of appearance doesn't affect anything if the pseudo-classes are different

Comment: Regarding the ordering see http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Comment: I have to admit, I somehow completely dismissed the thought of two pseudo classes being active at the same time. Thank you for the reminder.